# In what instances would a GA4 session ID have 2 different user pseudo ids?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

So I've been sorting out tracking and reporting on a new website using GA4 with a Big Query export.

As I've started building a report I've found 5 session IDs (out of a few hundred) that have 2 different user pseudo ids attached to them.

Any ideas why/when this would happen?

While I would expect one pseudo user id to have have more than one session id, I was only expecting each session id to only have one user pseudo id.

The only thing I thought it might be is if cookies were deleted during a session but I've tried this and the same pseudo used id persists if I change page (my page changes are just history changes) or I get a new pseudo id AND session id if I hard refresh.

Comment: Do you have any app data imported from Firebase there?

Comment: Also show the screenshot of your BQ with the field names in question. GA4 has a few fields named quite poorly. For example, `ga_session_id` in `event_params` is a simple unix timestamp and not a random ID, so it can be safely expected to have users with the same `ga_session_id` when their start events happen in the same second.

Answer (score 1):

`ga_session_id`s are unique to `user_pseudo_id`/`user_id`s. That means to identify a unique session in your property, you need to have a composite key of `ga_session_id` and `user_pseudo_id`. You can see the official/standard method of identifying and calculating sessions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2022/hll#sessions). (Disclaimer: I wrote the linked article).

Answer (score 0):

ga_session_ids are basically a time stamp when the session started linked to an
event, its possible for multiple visits to happen at the same time.
Its the user_pseudo_id that defines the events are from different users so combining them will give you the correct number of sessions

```
count(distinct concat(user_pseudo_id,(select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id'))) as sessions
```